# Google Scripts Move An Image

Tags: google-apps-script

Salutations!

So I mainly programmed in Python and are relatively new to javascript. I'm currently trying to make a basic game to start to understand javascript. I only just stumbled across google scripts a few hours ago and I think it's really neat idea that allows for an easier time to develop web applications (which is seems Google is all about) having a GUI creation tool right along side is also a very nice feature.

But onto my problem. How do I actually move an image in javascript? I've found

```
  var obj = document.getElementById('IMG_Yellow_SW');
  obj.style.top = 50;
  obj.style.left = 50;
```

however I get a '"document" is not defined' error.

Comment: We're going to need to see more code than that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to understand that Google Script and JavaScript are very different in their capabilities but share the same syntax and many 'basic' objects such as String, Date, Array etc.

Google Script, unlike Javascript, cannot work with the DOM. Google Script generally resides in its own container and cannot influence objects outside it.

I suggest you begin with trying out some of the tutorials from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles